# Different results in a mixed model when compared with raw data

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I ran a model with reaction time as my DV and PWI Condition (2 levels) as one of the fixed factors.

I used contr.sum for all fixed factors. I ran the following model to look for differences in reaction time scores across three different IV's (2 levels each).

```
test=lmer(PWI_RT ~ PWI_Condition * Distractor_Condition * Distractor_Language + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Picture_Name), data=data1 ,],)
```

The output is as follows:

```
Random effects:
Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
Picture_Name (Intercept)   75160   274.2  
Subject      (Intercept)  121602   348.7  
Residual                 2522008  1588.1  
Number of obs: 1862, groups:  Picture_Name, 114; Subject, 19


Fixed effects:
                               Estimate | Std. Error | t value 
(Intercept)                    3605.485 |   77.181   |  46.71
PWI_Condition1                 109.131  |   30.595   |   3.57 
Dist_Condition1                -65.106  |   37.723   |  -1.73 
Dist_Language1                 -36.971  |   38.846   |  -0.95
PWI_Condition1:Dist_Condition1 -49.290  |   37.734   |  -1.31
PWI_Condition1:Dist_Language1   21.732  |   38.843   |   0.56
Dist_Condition1:Dist_Language1  35.925  |   37.797   |   0.95
PWI:Dist_Cond:Dist_Lang          6.284  |   37.801   |   0.17
```

The output (deviation coded) shows a positive t value of 3.57 for the PWI condition where Noncognates are coded (-1) and cognates are coded (+1). Hence, I interpret this as cognates take significantly longer to name than non-cognates. However, when I look at the raw data cognates take 809ms to be named whereas non-cognates take 849ms to be named suggesting that non-cognates take longer than cognates to be named. How can I explain this difference in result?

Comment: Double check your codings for the other variables. With the interactions you may accidentally be looking at simple effects not main effects. Also, is this balanced data (or at least nearly balanced)? Did the model converge or are you looking at the last iteration of a non-converged model?

Comment: I re-checked the codings to be sure. The data is not balanced. I have more number of Non-cognate pictures than Cognate pictures. Also, the model converged. I also ran the model without interactions (used + instead of *) and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Please show the full model summary.

Comment: I've included the full model summary in the question. Pardon the format.

Comment: I say trouble shoot this like its computer code since you know approximately what the inputs and outputs are.. If the problem lies with the other variables, do a model without any other variables `lmer(PWI_RT ~ PWI_Condition + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Picture_Name), data=data1)` and see what happens. If the problem is with the mixed model, try `summary(lm(PWI_RT ~ PWI_Condition, data=data1)`. If in that model the estimate is still off, recheck codings. Recheck your means. The only other thing I can think of is you set your codings after your made your model. So try rerunning the original model.

Answer (score 1):

Because you include the `PWI_Condition` in a 3-way interaction you can no longer interpret the main effect estimate in the way that you are trying to do. In the presence of an interaction the main effect is now the estimated change in the outcome when the other variables that are interacted with are zero. You may want to change the codings to 0/1 if this does not make sense in the context of your study